# VM crashing and messing up host?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am using Oracle VirtualBox 5.2.8 r121009 to use a 64 bit Windows 10 virtual machine. Occasionally but increasingly so, the VM has crashed while I am using it. This results in the screen turning black completely for a few seconds, and when it turns back on, the time on the host machine is off and the network is disconnected. I have to manually reset the time or restart the host. Often, the VM shows a blue screen of death afterward and VirtualBox shows an alert saying that there has been an error and memory could not be referenced.

I mainly use the VM for light tasks so I cannot think of a reason why it randomly aborts. This originally started months ago with a VM with 10 GB of virtual memory. Since then I have deleted it and retired with a new one with 2 GB and it has persisted.

How can I use the VM normally without these interruptions?

Comment: What makes you think the VM is messing up the host? It is MUCH more likely the host has a problem that is messing up the VM. Probably bad RAM, or a funky antivirus program.

Comment: @Appleoddity It only happens when I'm using the VM, so that was my best guess.